# Conversion from UIImage to BitMap and then that Bitmap to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, bitmap, uiimage, nsdata

I need to know the following 2 things:

1. I have an app in which I get a UIImage from a server which needs to be converted into Bitmap. How to convert it in Bitmap?
2. After converting the UIImage to bitmap , the bitmap buffer has to be converted into NSData (I do not want to use **UIImagePNGRepresentation** or **UIImageJPEGRepresentation** to get NSData). I need to send this NSData to the server.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`? That would be the way to do this.

Comment: Because I do not want to return the image data as PNG pr JPEG format.

Comment: When you say bitmap, do you mean something like BMP, or completely raw pixel data?

Comment: I have got the bitmap image using a tutorial. I just to know if there is any way by which I can get nsData with out using the mentioned methods.

Comment: What code do you use to get the bitmap data? Can you please post the code?

Comment: http://paulsolt.com/2010/09/ios-converting-uiimage-to-rgba8-bitmaps-and-back/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126772/objective-c-save-uiimage-as-a-bmp-file